# Running two ssh commands on a remote server with php

Tags: php, ssh

I'd like to run two remote commands onto a linux server using php.
The first one is this:

```
/opt/IBM/ITM/JRE/lx8266/bin/java  -Xmx3145728k -jar AggregationAnalyzer.jar /opt/IBM/ITM2/lx8263/to/bin/todata
```

it gets me the following video result:

```
Reading /opt/IBM/ITM2/lx8263/to/bin/todata/topology/MetaData.xml
Processing 864 records
0%       25%       50%       75%     100%
|---------+---------+---------+---------|
|.......................................|
Found 864 records in 2.41s. There were 0 records with missing RecordIdentity.xml
Writing HTML report to /opt/sw/db_viewer/todata_summary.html
Writing CSV report to /opt/sw/db_viewer/todata_raw.csv
```

The second one has to start only before the end of the previous one and it is:

```
cat /opt/sw/db_viewer/todata_summary.html
```

The initial part of php scripting is the following:

```
<?php

 include('C:\Manutenzione\Analisi_TT\simple_html_dom.php');

$ip_soatt04='myIP';

$usr_soatt = 'root';
$pwd_soatt = 'pwd';
$dom = new DomDocument();

    
    $connection_soatt04 = ssh2_connect($ip_soatt04, 22);
    
    if (!$connection_soatt04)
    {
        echo "impossibile connettersi a soatt04";
    }
        
    ssh2_auth_password($connection_soatt04, $usr_soatt , $pwd_soatt);
    
    $exec=ssh2_exec($connection_soatt04,'/opt/IBM/ITM/JRE/lx8266/bin/java  -Xmx3145728k -jar AggregationAnalyzer.jar /opt/IBM/ITM2/lx8263/to/bin/todata');
    
    $stream = ssh2_exec($connection_soatt04,'cat /opt/sw/db_viewer/todata_summary.html');
    
    stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
    
    $stream_out=stream_get_contents($stream);
    //$stream_out=file_get_html($stream,true);
    
    //echo $stream_out;

    $dom->loadHTML($stream_out);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
    [...]
```

I don't write the whole script because of using it with only the second command it works fine, but now I need to run the first command in order to generate the file I have to read, i.e. "todata_summary.html".
If I use the code above it doesn't work and I get an empty result.

Comment: How would your second script know that `todata_summary.html` has been created, except by running them in sequence instead of concurrently?

Comment: I find a way to do this, but I don't understand why the first command does not run in ssh. If I run it onto ssh directly it works.

Comment: Try logging the result so you can see what happens.   `-Xloggc:/tmp/gc.log `

Comment: So your question should _actually_ be "why does this first command not work via ssh?" and the other command or the sequence in which they are run is irrelevant and confuses the issue.

Comment: @Sammitch you're right but I figuerd it out after.